# Can't get to display item tab from rss feed in my objective c code for iOS app?

Tags: ios, rss

I am building an horoscope app for self use by using rss feed. RSS feed that I selected updates regularly and show all horoscopes. I want to show horoscope's name and then detail.
I am using feed from http://my.horoscope.com/astrology/daily-horoscopes-rss.html.
My code is only showing description but not title from rss. I want it to first show the star name and when user press on the desired star, it opens its details. Here is the code:

```
    -(void)fetchRssWithURL:(NSURL*)url complete:(RSSLoaderCompleteBlock)callbackFunction
    {
    // Create url connection and fire request
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] init];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    (void)[conn initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
           {
                   NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                   if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil) {
                           // handle empty response
                       } else if (error != nil) {
                               // handle error
                               NSLog(@"Error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                           } else if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {
                                   RXMLElement *rss = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLData:data];
                                   RXMLElement *rssChild = [rss child:@"channel"];
                                   RXMLElement* title = [rssChild child:@"title"];
                                   NSArray* items = [[rss child:@"channel"] children:@"item"];

                                   NSMutableArray* result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:items.count];

                                   //more code
                                   for (RXMLElement *e in items) {

                                           //iterate over the articles
                                           RSSItem* item = [[RSSItem alloc] init];
                                           item.title = [[e child:@"title"] text];
                                           item.description = [[e child:@"description"] text];
                                           item.link = [NSURL URLWithString: [[e child:@"link"] text]];
                                           if (item.link != NULL) {
                                                   [result addObject: item];
                                               }
                                       }

                                   callbackFunction([title text], result);
                               }
               }];

    }
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and worked through your code in the debugger to see what is happening?

Comment: yes, it works fine. It runs and shows the output correctly except that i want it to show title field then after selecting, it should fetch details from link in rss's link field. Which apparently it doesn't and show only description instead of title. I am either missing something where it iterates over the article or my code there needs to get adjustment. Help please. Thank you.

Comment: Then you will need some more code somewhere to fetch the link.  Simply creating an NSURL won't actually connect to the server to retrieve the content